# Peeking a GTK event; gtk.gdk.event_peek always returns None

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I need to check whether the Escape key has been pressed during execution of some non-GUI code. (The code is in Python, but can easily call into C if necessary.) The code received a function from the GUI that it occasionally calls to check whether it has been interrupted. The question is how to implement this check.

By looking at the documentation, `gdk_event_peek` seems like an excellent choice for this:

```
def _check_esc(self):
    event = gtk.gdk.event_peek()
    if event is None or event.type not in (gtk.gdk.KEY_PRESS, gtk.gdk.KEY_RELEASE):
        return False
    return gtk.gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval) == 'Escape'
```

This doesn't work, however: the event returned from `gtk.gdk.event_peek()` is always None when the main loop is not running. Changing it to `gtk.gdk.display_get_default().peek_event()` doesn't help either. I assume the events are in the X event queue and are not yet moved to the GDK event queue. [The documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/GdkDisplay.html#gdk-display-peek-event) says:

> Note that this function will not get more events from the windowing
>   system. It only checks the events that have already been moved to the
>   GDK event queue.

So, how does one transfer the event to the GDK event queue or? In other words, when does `gtk.gdk.peek_event()` ever return an event? Calling `gtk.events_pending()` doesn't have any effect.

Here is a minimal program to test it:

```
import gtk, gobject
import time

def code(check):
    while 1:
        time.sleep(.1)
        if check():
            print 'interrupted'
            return

def _check_esc():
    event = gtk.gdk.event_peek()
    print 'event:', event
    if event is None or event.type not in (gtk.gdk.KEY_PRESS, gtk.gdk.KEY_RELEASE):
        return False
    return gtk.gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval) == 'Escape'

def runner():
    code(_check_esc)
    gtk.main_quit()

w = gtk.Window()
w.show()
gobject.idle_add(runner)
gtk.main()
```

When running the code, the event printed is always None, even if you press Escape or move the mouse.

I also considered installing a handler for Escape and having the checker process events with the `while gtk.events_pending(): gtk.main_iteration()` idiom. This results in unqueuing and dispatch of *all* pending events, including keyboard and mouse events. The effect is that the GUI is responsive enabled while the code runs, which doesn't look well and can severely interfere with the execution of the code. The *only* event processed during execution should be the escape key to interrupt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a `runner` implementation that satisfies the criteria put forward in the question:

```
def runner():
    # _check_esc searches for Escape in our queue
    def _check_esc():
        oldpos = len(queue)
        while gtk.events_pending():
            gtk.main_iteration()
        new = itertools.islice(queue, oldpos, None)
        return any(event.type == gtk.gdk.KEY_PRESS \
                       and gtk.gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval) == 'Escape'
                   for event in new)

    queue = []
    # temporarily set the global event handler to queue
    # the events
    gtk.gdk.event_handler_set(queue.append)
    try:
        code(_check_esc)
    finally:
        # restore the handler and replay the events
        handler = gtk.main_do_event
        gtk.gdk.event_handler_set(gtk.main_do_event)
        for event in queue:
            handler(event)
    gtk.main_quit()
```

Compared to a peek-based solution, its advantage is that it handles the case when another event arrives after the keypress. The disadvantage is that it requires fiddling with the global event handler.

Comment: New GDK events are added to queue and later analyzed in _check_esc. But how do they magically turn into GTK events and end up in gtk's event queue? In other words, how does gtk.events_pending ever learn about those?